# Radius of an arc in java

Tags: java, swing

```
// The class for drawing arcs on a panel
1  class ArcsPanel extends JPanel {
2   @Override
3   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
4     super.paintComponent(g);
5 
6     int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
7     int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
8     int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);
9 
10    int x = xCenter - radius;
11    int y = yCenter - radius;
12
13    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
14    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
15    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
16    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);
17  }
18}
```

i do not understand line 8. Explanation of the formula of getting radius. From where does he get 0.4 in radius formula? i did not find the formula.
finding the radius of an arc is different.

I found it from " Introduction to Java Programming, Comprehensive Version (9th Edition); Listing 13.4 example; page : 489 (522 / 1947) "

Answer (score 2):

The `0.4` seems to be a relative value, meaning "the corner radius is 40% of the lesser of width and height".

EDIT: This is an perfect example, why uncommented code and magic constants are bad. Normally, you would use a variable or a parameter instead of a magic constant.